# How to show navigation tab when it was already mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, state-management

I have hidden TabNavigator (`react-navigation`), and I need to show it after property event changed.

My component:

```
export default class Quotes extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;

    return {
      tabBarVisible: params && params.showNavigation
    };
  };

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ showNavigation: this.props.profileCreated });
  }

  render() {
  ...
  }
}
```

I manipulate `tabBarVisible` with `showNavigation` option that connected to `this.props.profileCreated`. But I don't know where to move this code, to check every time props changed. When I'm trying to move it to `render` or `componentWillReceiveProps` it's not allowed to setState there.

**Updated**

When I'm trying to add:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (!this.props.profileCreated && nextProps.profileCreated) {
    this.props.navigation.setParams(
      { showNavigation: this.props.profileCreated }
    );
  }
}
```

I have next warnings:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:71 Warning: Quotes: Did not properly initialize state during construction. Expected state to be an object, but it was undefined.
...
Quotes.js:25 getDerivedStateFromProps
Quotes.js:26 {screenProps: undefined, navigation: {…}, unsubmitted: Array(0), quotes: {…}, fields: {…}, …}
ExceptionsManager.js:71 Warning: 
Quotes.getDerivedStateFromProps(): A valid state object (or null) must be returned. You have returned undefined.
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can use componentWillReceiveProps, but you just need to add an if statement to ensure you don't end up in the infinite update loop:

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

  if (!this.props.profileCreated && nextProps.profileCreated) {
    this.props.navigation.setParams(
      { showNavigation: this.props.profileCreated }
    );
  }
}
```

However, it's recommended to use the static method **getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)** now. This method is called whenever a component gets updated (and also on initial mount).

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (!this.props.profileCreated && nextProps.profileCreated) {
    this.props.navigation.setParams(
      { showNavigation: this.props.profileCreated }
    );
  }
  return {} // or any state change you need
}
```

Comment: Both doesn't work. Because `profileCreated` changes on another page and when focus get back on this page, both props are already `profileCreated`. So I need to check somehow, that it's hidden, but profile created.

Comment: But if the condition - `this.props.navigation.state.showNavigation` - it goes in an infinite loop.

Comment: I saw you edit, I forgot to return the state objecty from getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: You always need to check the current props versus the previous props when updating. So your check would be something like: this.props.profileCreated && this.props.navigation.state.params.showNavigation && !prevProps.navigation.state.params.showNavigation

Comment: I tried a lot of options, but it's always infinite loop. I think I'll recreate question with more details.

Comment: Also I'm not using any state in my component, I'm using Redux. So, the only state has a `navigation` component. Maybe I should change it there. Cause when I set `params: {showNavigation: false}` in that state, it shows panel anyway.

Comment: Ah Redux, that could really help here! Could you add the entire component code?